# Self-hosted IR Node is unavailable and activities get timeout in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

Azure Data Factory pipeline have been working fine for 2 years with Self-hosted Integration runtime (Azure VM 16GB)
In last few weeks pipeline have got very unreliable and data is no longer processed correctly.

Data Factory Activity using "MyAzureIntegrationRuntime" instance is failing with "timeout" error.
Some of activities get successfully completed, but most of them get failed.
ADF Monitor tell that node is "Unavailable". Typical ADF activity is Azure SQL lookup.

There is no event log errors in Virtual Machine. There seems to be enough CPU/RAM to execute IR activities.
Reboot of VM has once helped to recover connectivity and pipelines.
However latest VM reboot restored status to "Running" from “Unavailable”, but many pipeline activities get failed.

Integration Runtime is currently not in High Available Cluster.
There is single VM serving Sandbox, Dev, Test and Prod ADF. It has worked fine for last years except last 2 weeks.

How could I find what is the problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I find what is the problem and fixed it?

For failed activities that are running on a self-hosted IR or a shared IR, the service supports viewing and uploading error logs. To get the error report ID, follow the instructions here, and then enter the report ID to search for related known issues.

1. On the Monitor page for the service UI, select Pipeline runs.
2. Under **Activity runs**, in the **Error** column, select the highlighted button to display the activity logs, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image]

The activity logs are displayed for the failed activity run.

[image]

3. For further assistance, select Send logs.

The Share the self-hosted integration runtime (IR) logs with Microsoft window opens.

[image]

4. Select which logs you want to send.

- For a self-hosted IR, you can upload logs that are related to the failed activity or all logs on the self-hosted IR node.
- For a shared IR, you can upload only logs that are related to the failed activity.

5. When the logs are uploaded, keep a record of the Report ID for later use if you need further assistance to solve the issue.

[image]